# Fastify - Schema required field is an object key

Tags: jsonschema, fastify

When creating a Schema in Fastify, how can you set an object key as required? The fields I need as required are `amount` & `redirectUrl` and they're both contained within the `transaction` object.

I've tried `transaction.amount` but it doesn't work.

```
const createTransactionSchema = {
    body: {
        type: 'object',
        additionalProperties: false,
        required: ['merchantUuid', 'transaction'],
        properties: {
            merchantUuid: { type: 'string' },
            transaction: {
                type: 'object',
                required: ['amount', 'redirectUrl', 'address1'],
                properties: {
                    amount: { type: 'number', format: 'float', minimum: 0.01, maximum: 99999.99 },
                    redirectUrl: { type: 'string' },
                    address1: { type: 'string' },
                    city: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    email: { type: 'string', format: 'email', nullable: true },
                    firstName: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    invoiceId: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    message: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    mobile: { type: 'integer', nullable: true },
                    postcode: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    reference: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    service: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    surname: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
                    tableNumber: { type: 'integer', nullable: true },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    response: {
        200: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
                uuid: { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `required` keyword inside the `type: object` that wants the field:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: !true })

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  additionalProperties: false,
  required: ['merchantUuid', 'transaction'],
  properties: {
    merchantUuid: { type: 'string' },
    transaction: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['amount', 'redirectUrl', 'address1'],
      properties: {
        amount: { type: 'number', format: 'float', minimum: 0.01, maximum: 99999.99 },
        redirectUrl: { type: 'string' },
        address1: { type: 'string' },
        city: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        email: { type: 'string', format: 'email', nullable: true },
        firstName: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        invoiceId: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        message: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        mobile: { type: 'integer', nullable: true },
        postcode: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        reference: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        service: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        surname: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
        tableNumber: { type: 'integer', nullable: true }
      }
    }
  }
}

fastify.post('/', {
  schema: {
    body: schema,
    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: { uuid: { type: 'string' } }
      }
    }
  }
}, async (request, reply) => {
  return { uuid: JSON.stringify(request.body) }
})

call({}) // Error
call({ merchantUuid: 'asd' }) // Error (transaction is required)
call({ merchantUuid: 'asd', transaction: { } }) // Error
call({ merchantUuid: 'asd', transaction: { amount: 1 } }) // Error
call({ merchantUuid: 'asd', transaction: { amount: 1, redirectUrl: 'asd' } }) // Error
call({ merchantUuid: 'asd', transaction: { amount: 1, redirectUrl: 'asd', address1: 'foo' } }) // Works

function call (payload) {
  fastify.inject({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    payload
  }).then(resp => console.log(resp.json()))
}
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, I've just updated my code in the original post and tried testing it by making ```address1``` mandatory. If I do; ```call({ merchantUuid: 'asd', transaction: { amount: 1.00, redirectUrl: https://google.com } })```, it's not throwing an error even though it should as ```address1``` should be required now based on the updated code.

Comment: Updated the code - it works as expected so I suppose there is something else that is missing on the question code